# In my code of html there is a problem for showing the responsive output for the <select> tag and its output

Tags: html, select

[this is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF2Th.png)]
[this is the snap of the code written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brMpO.png)

i would like to show the select down menu for the cars . but when i am writing the code twice it is showing only one time for the output

```
<select name="cars" size="3" multiple>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would suggest you use checkboxes instead